# Getting error "provisioning profile doesn't include nslocationalwaysusagedescription" when uploading application to Apple store

Tags: ios, xcode

I am desperately trying to upload my application on the apple store, but when I do "product > archive", I am getting the following error:

> provisioning profile doesn't include nslocationalwaysusagedescription

How am I suppose to include this in the provisionning profile? I don't see anything about this in developer apple com.

EDIT--

I edited my info.plist to add nslocationalwaysusagedescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription because it is now required for the apple store. The error occured since i've added these two keys in info.plist. I understand that I must add these entitlements to the provisionning profile, but how do I add entitlements to my release provisionning profile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why,

In cordova we have two plist files, one called "Entitlements-Release.plist" and one called "[appname]-Info.plist". I put the entitlements in "Entitlements-Release.plist" instead of "[appname]-Info.plist".  I don't know why the error wpeaks about provisionning profile but ater I removed the entitlements from the wrong plist it worked again.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you have not given the location permission in info.plist file. Make sure that you have given this permission.

> "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description" in info.plist file.

[image: Info.plist Image]

Comment: Hello, I've already set those permissions, the error seems to come from the provisionning profile

Comment: Thanks @vacawama, that's what I was looking for. I don't know why question was getting down voted.

Comment: People don't like "give me the code" questions.  It is best to show what you've attempted to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Sure @vacawama, thanks but I was not getting the way how to achieve this. Thanks for the help and suggestions.